# Cassandra improve failover time

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, failover, opscenter

We are using a 3-node cassandra cluster (each node on a different vm) and currently investigating failover times during write and read operations in case one of the nodes dies.
Failover times are pretty good when shutting down one node gracefully, however, when killing a node (by shutting down the VM) the latency during the tests is about 12 seconds. I guess this has something to do with the tcp timeout?

Is there any way to tweak this?

**Edit:** 
At the moment we are using Cassandra Version 2.0.10.
We are using the java client driver, version 2.1.9.

To describe the situation in more detail:
The write/read operations are performed using the **QUROUM** Consistency Level with a replication factor of 3. The cluster consists of 3 nodes (`c1,c2,c3`), each on a different host (VM). The client driver is connected to `c1`. During the tests I shutdown the host for `c2`. From then on we observe that the client is blocking for > 12 seconds, until the other nodes realize that `c2` is gone. So i think this is not a client issue, since the client is connected to node `c1`, which is still running in this scenario.

**Edit:** I don't believe that the fact that running cassandra inside a VM affects the network stack. In fact, killing the VM has the effect, that the TCP connections are not terminated. In this case, a remote host can notice this only through some time out mechanism (either a timeout on the application level protocol or a TCP timeout).
If the process is killed on OS level, the TCP stack of the OS will take care of terminating the TCP connection (IMHO with a TCP reset) enabling a remote host to immediately be notified about the failure. 
However, it might be important that even in situations, where a host crashes due to a hardware failure, or where a host is disconnected due to an unplugged network cable (in both cases the TCP connection will not be terminated immediately) the failover time is low.  I've tried to **sigkill** the cassandra process inside the VM. In this case the failover time is about 600ms, which is fine.

kind regards

Comment: I'm wondering whether the fact that you're running on a VM can affect the network stack. Indeed, can you retry the test by killing the Cassandra process (kill -9) in the VM instead of shutting down the VM itself to see if it does increase the latency ?

Comment: @doanduyhai Thanks for your input, I've edited the question.

Comment: When you shutdown a VM, did you see some messages in /var/log/cassandra/system.log from the 2 remaining nodes saying that the other node is down ? Also, you can configure the `phi_convict_threshold` in `cassandra.yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failover times are pretty good when shutting down one node gracefully, however, when killing a node (by shutting down the VM) the latency during the tests is about 12 seconds

12 secs is a pretty huge value. Some questions before investigating further

- what is your Cassandra version ? Since version **2.0.2** there is a speculative retry mechanism that help reducing the latency for such failover scenario: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/rapid-read-protection-in-cassandra-2-0-2
- what is the client driver you're using (java ? c# ? version ?). Normally with a properly configured load balancing policy, when a node is down the client will retry automatically the query by re-routing to another replica. There is also speculative retry implemented at the driver-side : http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/speculative_execution/

**Edit**: for a node to be marked down, the gossip protocol is using the phi accrual detector. Instead of having a binary state (UP/DOWN), the algorithm adjust the suspicion level and if the value is above a threshold, the node is considered down

This algorithm is necessary to avoid marking down a node because of a micro network issue.

Look in the `cassandra.yaml` file for this config:

```
# phi value that must be reached for a host to be marked down.
# most users should never need to adjust this.
# phi_convict_threshold: 8
```

Another question is: **what load balancing strategy are you using from the driver** ? And did you use the speculative retry policy ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited the question according to your request.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the phi value does not make any difference, still about 12 secons latency. I've set it to 5. I am not explicitly using any load balancing strategy from the driver, should this make any difference in my test scenario? What are you suggesting?

Comment: Try out the speculative retry load balancing strategy

Comment: What LoadBalancingPolicy are you using for your driver? Do you also see the same delay when using a cqlsh query on one of the other nodes? i.e. is the problem between the cluster nodes or the client and the cluster.

Comment: Did you try bringing the request timeouts down to 1 or 2 secs ?

Comment: @markc I am currently not using any LoadBalancingPolicy for the driver. I am pretty sure that this is a problem between the nodes. The situation is always the same: I am writing to node c1. As soon as I am shutting down the VM of node c2, the write operations in my tests get stucked, until the other nodes realize that node c2 is gone. This takes about 12 seconds (I see it in the logs of node c1 - it takes about 12 seconds after shutdown of c2 until i read "Node C2 DOWN in the logs of c1"). As soon as they realize that c2 is down, the write operations continue.

Comment: @PatrickCallaghan yes I've tried it - it makes no difference. The thing is, that when I am shutting down the VM of a node, it takes about 12 seconds until the other node realize that the node is gone. Maybe I need to tweak some parameters of the gossip algorithm?

Comment: @user1291235 is it possible to take the driver out of the mix, and do some reading / writing with cqlsh while you take a node out of the cluster? this will then determine if the problem is between the client and the cluster or just within the cluster

Comment: @markc yes, I've already tried to fire queries manually via cqlsh inside this time frame and the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Activate query tracing with cqlsh before firing the request to see what happen server-side `TRACING ON`

Comment: @markc ok, I noticed that, when I am manually firing events from an external tool like for example "DBEAVER" I get the same behavior like in my tests, however if I am **directly** using cqlsh for querying (using consistency level quorum as well of course), it works perfectly without blocking 12 seconds ! Maybe it is indeed a problem of the java client driver...

Comment: Right so you could wrap your driver LoadBalancing policy (which are chainable) in the "LatencyAwarePolicy" or one of the others? I dont know if the driver should wait that long before switching nodes in the pool but the fact that you have a pool of connections means it should switch over to another contact point. Have a look at the LoadBalancing policy docs here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/LoadBalancingPolicy.html. Also very good article on connection poolin here: http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/pooling/

Comment: @markc I've managed to drastically reduce the failover time using a combi of SpeculativeRetryPolicy and a custom LBP using latency threadholds. I guess I am satisfied with the failover time, thank you for your help :) However, the time until a node is really marked "down" in case of a sudden VM switchoff is still about 12 seconds from a cluster point of view (reduced phi val to 5). Just for my interest: is this just normal behavior (for reasons I described in the question)? Nodes are "immediately" marked down when killing the cassandra process, but it takes a lot of seconds in case of VM kill.

Comment: Well as you said yourself earlier "In fact, killing the VM has the effect, that the TCP connections are not terminated. In this case, a remote host can notice this only through some time out mechanism (either a timeout on the application level protocol or a TCP timeout)"

Comment: @doanduyhai alright :) You've basically suggested the options that helped me to solve the problem - I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!